# Disjunction introduction in Hilbert system (3 axioms)

Tags: logic

We have Hilbert system with axioms

1. $A \to (B \to A)$,
2. $\big(A \to (B \to C)\big) \to \big((A \to B) \to (A \to C)\big)$,
3. $(\neg B \to \neg A) \to \big((\neg B \to A) \to B\big)$

with modus ponens rule: $\cfrac{A,\ A \to B}{B}$.

How can we prove $A \to (A \lor B)$, which means $A \to (\neg A \to B)$?

Comment: Are you allowed to use the Deduction Theorem?

Comment: @DanielSchepler Let's suppose it's allowed. I think, it would be interesting to prove this with Deduction Theorem and avoiding it

Comment: OK, so using the deductino theorem twice, let's suppose we have assumptions $A$ and $\lnot A$, and we want to conclude $B$.  Axiom 3 looks promising: can you prove, using the assumptions, that $\lnot B \rightarrow \lnot A$ and $\lnot B \rightarrow A$ are both true?

Comment: Yes, we can: we get $\neg B \to A$ from axiom $A \to (\neg B \to A)$ with MP and $\neg B \to \neg A$ similarly

Answer (score 1):

To illustrate what it would be like in Hilbert-style derivation, I give a proof employing no theorems ready at hand, nor meta-theorems.

I shall use the variation of the Axiom 3, $(\neg A\rightarrow\neg B)\rightarrow (B\rightarrow A)$, which I am accustomed to, instead of the one given in the question:

1. $(\neg\neg\neg\neg\neg A\rightarrow\neg\neg\neg A)\rightarrow (\neg\neg A\rightarrow\neg\neg\neg\neg A)\qquad\text{Ax 3}$
2. $\big((\neg\neg\neg\neg\neg A\rightarrow\neg\neg\neg A)\rightarrow (\neg\neg A\rightarrow\neg\neg\neg\neg A)\big)\rightarrow\Big(\neg\neg\neg A\rightarrow\big((\neg\neg\neg\neg\neg A\rightarrow\neg\neg\neg A)\rightarrow(\neg\neg A\rightarrow\neg\neg\neg\neg A)\big)\Big)\qquad\text{Ax 1}$
3. $\neg\neg\neg A\rightarrow\big((\neg\neg\neg\neg\neg A\rightarrow\neg\neg\neg A)\rightarrow(\neg\neg A\rightarrow\neg\neg\neg\neg A)\big)\qquad\text{MP 1, 2}$
4. $\Big(\neg\neg\neg A\rightarrow\big((\neg\neg\neg\neg\neg A\rightarrow\neg\neg\neg A)\rightarrow(\neg\neg A\rightarrow\neg\neg\neg\neg A)\big)\Big)\rightarrow\Big(\big(\neg\neg\neg A\rightarrow(\neg\neg\neg\neg\neg A\rightarrow\neg\neg\neg A)\big)\rightarrow\big(\neg\neg\neg A\rightarrow(\neg\neg A\rightarrow\neg\neg\neg\neg A)\big)\Big)\qquad\text{Ax 2}$
5. $\big(\neg\neg\neg A\rightarrow(\neg\neg\neg\neg\neg A\rightarrow\neg\neg\neg A)\big)\rightarrow\big(\neg\neg\neg A\rightarrow(\neg\neg A\rightarrow\neg\neg\neg\neg A)\big)\qquad\text{MP 3, 4}$
6. $\neg\neg\neg A\rightarrow(\neg\neg\neg\neg\neg A\rightarrow\neg\neg\neg A)\qquad\text{Ax 1}$
7. $\neg\neg\neg A\rightarrow(\neg\neg A\rightarrow\neg\neg\neg\neg A)\qquad\text{MP 5, 6}$
8. $(\neg\neg A\rightarrow\neg\neg\neg\neg A)\rightarrow (\neg\neg\neg A\rightarrow\neg A)\qquad\text{Ax 3}$
9. $\Big((\neg\neg A\rightarrow\neg\neg\neg\neg A)\rightarrow (\neg\neg\neg A\rightarrow\neg A)\Big)\rightarrow\Big(\neg\neg\neg A\rightarrow\big((\neg\neg A\rightarrow\neg\neg\neg\neg A)\rightarrow (\neg\neg\neg A\rightarrow\neg A)\big)\Big)\qquad\text{Ax 1}$
10. $\neg\neg\neg A\rightarrow\big((\neg\neg A\rightarrow\neg\neg\neg\neg A)\rightarrow (\neg\neg\neg A\rightarrow\neg A)\big)\qquad\text{MP 8, 9}$
11. $\Big(\neg\neg\neg A\rightarrow\big((\neg\neg A\rightarrow\neg\neg\neg\neg A)\rightarrow (\neg\neg\neg A\rightarrow\neg A)\big)\Big)\rightarrow\Big(\big(\neg\neg\neg A\rightarrow(\neg\neg A\rightarrow\neg\neg\neg\neg A)\big)\rightarrow\big(\neg\neg\neg A\rightarrow (\neg\neg\neg A\rightarrow\neg A)\big)\Big)\qquad\text{Ax 2}$
12. $\big(\neg\neg\neg A\rightarrow(\neg\neg A\rightarrow\neg\neg\neg\neg A)\big)\rightarrow\big(\neg\neg\neg A\rightarrow (\neg\neg\neg A\rightarrow\neg A)\big)\qquad\text{MP 10, 11}$
13. $\neg\neg\neg A\rightarrow (\neg\neg\neg A\rightarrow\neg A)\qquad\text{MP 7, 12}$
14. $\big(\neg\neg\neg A\rightarrow (\neg\neg\neg A\rightarrow\neg A)\big)\rightarrow\big((\neg\neg\neg A\rightarrow\neg\neg\neg A)\rightarrow(\neg\neg\neg A\rightarrow\neg A)\big)\qquad\text{Ax 2}$
15. $(\neg\neg\neg A\rightarrow\neg\neg\neg A)\rightarrow(\neg\neg\neg A\rightarrow\neg A)\qquad\text{MP 13, 14}$
16. $\neg\neg\neg A\rightarrow\big((\neg\neg\neg A\rightarrow\neg\neg\neg A)\rightarrow\neg\neg\neg A\big)\qquad\text{Ax 1}$
17. $\Big(\neg\neg\neg A\rightarrow\big((\neg\neg\neg A\rightarrow\neg\neg\neg A)\rightarrow\neg\neg\neg A\big)\Big)\rightarrow\Big(\big(\neg\neg\neg A\rightarrow(\neg\neg\neg A\rightarrow\neg\neg\neg A)\big)\rightarrow\big(\neg\neg\neg A\rightarrow\neg\neg\neg A\big)\Big)\qquad\text{Ax 2}$
18. $\big(\neg\neg\neg A\rightarrow(\neg\neg\neg A\rightarrow\neg\neg\neg A)\big)\rightarrow\big(\neg\neg\neg A\rightarrow\neg\neg\neg A\big)\qquad\text{MP 16, 17}$
19. $\neg\neg\neg A\rightarrow(\neg\neg\neg A\rightarrow\neg\neg\neg A)\qquad\text{Ax 1}$
20. $(\neg\neg\neg A\rightarrow\neg\neg\neg A)\qquad\text{MP 18, 19}$
21. $(\neg\neg\neg A\rightarrow\neg A)\qquad\text{MP 15, 20}$
22. $(\neg\neg\neg A\rightarrow\neg A)\rightarrow (A\rightarrow\neg\neg A)\qquad\text{Ax 3}$
23. $A\rightarrow\neg\neg A\qquad\text{MP 21, 22}$
24. $(\neg B\rightarrow\neg\neg A)\rightarrow (\neg A\rightarrow B)\qquad\text{Ax 3}$
25. $\big((\neg B\rightarrow\neg\neg A)\rightarrow (\neg A\rightarrow B)\big)\rightarrow\Big(\neg\neg A\rightarrow\big((\neg B\rightarrow\neg\neg A)\rightarrow (\neg A\rightarrow B)\big)\Big)\qquad\text{Ax 1}$
26. $\neg\neg A\rightarrow\big((\neg B\rightarrow\neg\neg A)\rightarrow (\neg A\rightarrow B)\big)\qquad\text{MP 24, 25}$
27. $\Big(\neg\neg A\rightarrow\big((\neg B\rightarrow\neg\neg A)\rightarrow (\neg A\rightarrow B)\big)\Big)\rightarrow\Big(\big(\neg\neg A\rightarrow(\neg B\rightarrow\neg\neg A)\big)\rightarrow\big(\neg\neg A\rightarrow (\neg A\rightarrow B)\big)\Big)\qquad\text{Ax 2}$
28. $\big(\neg\neg A\rightarrow(\neg B\rightarrow\neg\neg A)\big)\rightarrow\big(\neg\neg A\rightarrow (\neg A\rightarrow B)\big)\qquad\text{MP 26, 27}$
29. $\neg\neg A\rightarrow (\neg B\rightarrow\neg\neg A)\qquad\text{Ax 1}$
30. $\neg\neg A\rightarrow (\neg A\rightarrow B)\qquad\text{MP 28, 29}$
31. $\big(\neg\neg A\rightarrow (\neg A\rightarrow B)\big)\rightarrow\Big(A\rightarrow\big(\neg\neg A\rightarrow(\neg A\rightarrow B)\big)\Big)\qquad\text{Ax 1}$
32. $A\rightarrow\big(\neg\neg A\rightarrow(\neg A\rightarrow B)\big)\qquad\text{MP 30, 31}$
33. $\Big(A\rightarrow\big(\neg\neg A\rightarrow(\neg A\rightarrow B)\big)\Big)\rightarrow\Big((A\rightarrow\neg\neg A)\rightarrow\big(A\rightarrow(\neg A\rightarrow B)\big)\Big)\qquad\text{Ax 2}$
34. $(A\rightarrow\neg\neg A)\rightarrow\big(A\rightarrow(\neg A\rightarrow B)\big)\qquad\text{MP 32, 33}$
35. $A\rightarrow(\neg A\rightarrow B)\qquad\text{MP 23, 34}$