# Proving $A\to (¬A \to B)$ with Łukasiewicz's axioms and modus ponens?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, formal-proofs

I am trying to answer the following exercise from [Hao's Fundamentals of Logic and Computation: With Practical Automated Reasoning and Verification](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-030-87882-5).

> [image]

Using only modus ponens and the following axioms:

> [image]

I'm stuck for some days on it, [I've even made a small program in Mathematica to help me with the substitutions](https://i.imgur.com/uiVpxjn.png) but got nothing. Can you help me?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/152195/discussion-on-question-by-red-banana-proving-a-to-a-to-b-with-lukasiewicz); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 1):

Hou gives the rule of *transitivity of implication* (TI) on p. 17, but does not give the theorem $A\rightarrow\neg\neg A$. So, I copy the proof of this theorem from [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4534300/754923) and paste it here (lines 1—23) and the rest follows:

1. $(\neg\neg\neg\neg\neg A\rightarrow\neg\neg\neg A)\rightarrow (\neg\neg A\rightarrow\neg\neg\neg\neg A)\qquad\text{Ax 3}$
2. $\big((\neg\neg\neg\neg\neg A\rightarrow\neg\neg\neg A)\rightarrow (\neg\neg A\rightarrow\neg\neg\neg\neg A)\big)\rightarrow\Big(\neg\neg\neg A\rightarrow\big((\neg\neg\neg\neg\neg A\rightarrow\neg\neg\neg A)\rightarrow(\neg\neg A\rightarrow\neg\neg\neg\neg A)\big)\Big)\qquad\text{Ax 1}$
3. $\neg\neg\neg A\rightarrow\big((\neg\neg\neg\neg\neg A\rightarrow\neg\neg\neg A)\rightarrow(\neg\neg A\rightarrow\neg\neg\neg\neg A)\big)\qquad\text{MP 1, 2}$
4. $\Big(\neg\neg\neg A\rightarrow\big((\neg\neg\neg\neg\neg A\rightarrow\neg\neg\neg A)\rightarrow(\neg\neg A\rightarrow\neg\neg\neg\neg A)\big)\Big)\rightarrow\Big(\big(\neg\neg\neg A\rightarrow(\neg\neg\neg\neg\neg A\rightarrow\neg\neg\neg A)\big)\rightarrow\big(\neg\neg\neg A\rightarrow(\neg\neg A\rightarrow\neg\neg\neg\neg A)\big)\Big)\qquad\text{Ax 2}$
5. $\big(\neg\neg\neg A\rightarrow(\neg\neg\neg\neg\neg A\rightarrow\neg\neg\neg A)\big)\rightarrow\big(\neg\neg\neg A\rightarrow(\neg\neg A\rightarrow\neg\neg\neg\neg A)\big)\qquad\text{MP 3, 4}$
6. $\neg\neg\neg A\rightarrow(\neg\neg\neg\neg\neg A\rightarrow\neg\neg\neg A)\qquad\text{Ax 1}$
7. $\neg\neg\neg A\rightarrow(\neg\neg A\rightarrow\neg\neg\neg\neg A)\qquad\text{MP 5, 6}$
8. $(\neg\neg A\rightarrow\neg\neg\neg\neg A)\rightarrow (\neg\neg\neg A\rightarrow\neg A)\qquad\text{Ax 3}$
9. $\Big((\neg\neg A\rightarrow\neg\neg\neg\neg A)\rightarrow (\neg\neg\neg A\rightarrow\neg A)\Big)\rightarrow\Big(\neg\neg\neg A\rightarrow\big((\neg\neg A\rightarrow\neg\neg\neg\neg A)\rightarrow (\neg\neg\neg A\rightarrow\neg A)\big)\Big)\qquad\text{Ax 1}$
10. $\neg\neg\neg A\rightarrow\big((\neg\neg A\rightarrow\neg\neg\neg\neg A)\rightarrow (\neg\neg\neg A\rightarrow\neg A)\big)\qquad\text{MP 8, 9}$
11. $\Big(\neg\neg\neg A\rightarrow\big((\neg\neg A\rightarrow\neg\neg\neg\neg A)\rightarrow (\neg\neg\neg A\rightarrow\neg A)\big)\Big)\rightarrow\Big(\big(\neg\neg\neg A\rightarrow(\neg\neg A\rightarrow\neg\neg\neg\neg A)\big)\rightarrow\big(\neg\neg\neg A\rightarrow (\neg\neg\neg A\rightarrow\neg A)\big)\Big)\qquad\text{Ax 2}$
12. $\big(\neg\neg\neg A\rightarrow(\neg\neg A\rightarrow\neg\neg\neg\neg A)\big)\rightarrow\big(\neg\neg\neg A\rightarrow (\neg\neg\neg A\rightarrow\neg A)\big)\qquad\text{MP 10, 11}$
13. $\neg\neg\neg A\rightarrow (\neg\neg\neg A\rightarrow\neg A)\qquad\text{MP 7, 12}$
14. $\big(\neg\neg\neg A\rightarrow (\neg\neg\neg A\rightarrow\neg A)\big)\rightarrow\big((\neg\neg\neg A\rightarrow\neg\neg\neg A)\rightarrow(\neg\neg\neg A\rightarrow\neg A)\big)\qquad\text{Ax 2}$
15. $(\neg\neg\neg A\rightarrow\neg\neg\neg A)\rightarrow(\neg\neg\neg A\rightarrow\neg A)\qquad\text{MP 13, 14}$
16. $\neg\neg\neg A\rightarrow\big((\neg\neg\neg A\rightarrow\neg\neg\neg A)\rightarrow\neg\neg\neg A\big)\qquad\text{Ax 1}$
17. $\Big(\neg\neg\neg A\rightarrow\big((\neg\neg\neg A\rightarrow\neg\neg\neg A)\rightarrow\neg\neg\neg A\big)\Big)\rightarrow\Big(\big(\neg\neg\neg A\rightarrow(\neg\neg\neg A\rightarrow\neg\neg\neg A)\big)\rightarrow\big(\neg\neg\neg A\rightarrow\neg\neg\neg A\big)\Big)\qquad\text{Ax 2}$
18. $\big(\neg\neg\neg A\rightarrow(\neg\neg\neg A\rightarrow\neg\neg\neg A)\big)\rightarrow\big(\neg\neg\neg A\rightarrow\neg\neg\neg A\big)\qquad\text{MP 16, 17}$
19. $\neg\neg\neg A\rightarrow(\neg\neg\neg A\rightarrow\neg\neg\neg A)\qquad\text{Ax 1}$
20. $(\neg\neg\neg A\rightarrow\neg\neg\neg A)\qquad\text{MP 18, 19}$
21. $(\neg\neg\neg A\rightarrow\neg A)\qquad\text{MP 15, 20}$
22. $(\neg\neg\neg A\rightarrow\neg A)\rightarrow (A\rightarrow\neg\neg A)\qquad\text{Ax 3}$
23. $A\rightarrow\neg\neg A\qquad\text{MP 21, 22}$
24. $\neg\neg A\rightarrow(\neg B\rightarrow\neg\neg A)\qquad\text{Ax 1}$
25. $(\neg B\rightarrow\neg\neg A)\rightarrow(\neg A\rightarrow B)\qquad\text{Ax 3}$
26. $\neg\neg A\rightarrow(\neg A\rightarrow B)\qquad\text{TI 24, 25}$
27. $A\rightarrow(\neg A\rightarrow B)\qquad\text{TI 23, 26}$

Answer (score 1):

Name the first two axioms as follows:
$$K: a → b → a,\quad S: (a → b → c) → (a → b) → a → c,$$
where we adopt the prevailing convention of of associating to the right, i.e. $a → b → c = a → (b → c)$. Name the third axiom
$$Z: (¬a → ¬b) → b → a,$$
and for modus ponens, applied to $f: a → b$ and $g: a$, write $fg: b$. Adopt the prevailing convention of associating products to the left, i.e. $fgh = (fg)h$. As is well-known, and as you can verify, there is an equivalence of proofs given by the following:
$$K f g = f,\quad S f g h = f h (g h).$$

Important lemmas can be stated as follows:
$$\begin{align}
I = S K K:& a → a,\\
B = S (K S) K:& (b → c) → (a → b) → a → c,\\
C = S (B B S) (K K):& (a → b → c) → b → a → c.
\end{align}$$
The corresponding formulas, derivable from those above, are
$$I f = f,\quad B f g h = f (g h),\quad C f g h = f h g.$$

The formulas are identical to those seen in [Combinatory Logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatory_logic) and may be interpreted as a system of type templates (and proof conversion rules), e.g. where the type for the combinator $I$ is the template consisting of all types of the form $a → a$, and a type $a → b$, in general, denotes the type of all functions that take arguments of type $a$ and return arguments of type $b$. This is none other than the [Curry-Howard Correspondence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curry%E2%80%93Howard_correspondence).

(That's why this question popped up in my feed, after I got through answering a bunch of combinator questions.)

One example of a proof derived by the η-rule (which corresponds to proof by discharge of hypothesis) is that since $S (K f) g h = K f h (g h) = f (g h) = B f g h$, then $S (K f) g = B f g$ and $S (K f) = B f$. I won't make direct use of that, other than to note a simplification of another reply given here.

As an example, the development of the proof for $B$ is given here:
$$\begin{align}
S:& (d → e → f) → (d → e) → d → f,\\
K:& g → d → g,\\
S:& (a → b → c) → (a → b) → a → c,\\
K S:& d → (a → b → c) → (a → b) → a → c,\\
S (K S):& (d → a → b → c) → d → (a → b) → a → c,\\
K:& d → a → d,\\
B = S (K S) K:& (b → c) → (a → b) → a → c,\\
\end{align}$$
where modus ponens is matched at the relevant points by the conditions
$$
d = b → c,\quad e = a → b → c,\quad f = (a → b) → a → c,\quad g = e → f.
$$

You can work out the development for the proofs of $I$ and $C$.

The (27 line) answer given in another reply corresponds to the term
$$B (B Z K) (Z (S (S (K Z) (S (K Z) K)) I))$$
as you can determine, for yourself, by carefully reading the attributions in the proof and constructing the term based on them. Since $S (K Z) = B Z$ (up to η-equivalence), this can be just as well written as
$$B V (Z (S (B Z V) I))$$
where $V = B Z K$.

Do we really need all that? What is the $V$ proof?
$$\begin{align}
B:& (d → e) → (c → d) → c → e,\\
Z:& (¬b → ¬a) → a → b,\\
B Z:& (c → ¬b → ¬a) → c → a → b,\\
K:& c → f → c,\\
B Z K:& ¬a → a → b,\\
\end{align}$$
where
$$c = ¬a,\quad d = ¬b → ¬a,\quad e = a → b,\quad f = ¬b$$
ensures Modus Ponens matches up at the relevant points. Run $C$ on this - which is why I brought it up:
$$\begin{align}
C:& (d → a → b) → a → d → b,\\
B Z K:& ¬a → a → b,\\
C (B Z K):& a → ¬a → b,
\end{align}$$
where
$$d = ¬a.$$

If you want to simplify it, run it through the combinator formulae:
$$C f = S (B B S) (K K) f = B B S f (K K f) = B (S f) K\quad (f = B Z K).$$
Thus, the proof is:
$$B (S (B Z K)) K = S (K (S (S (K Z) K))) K.$$

Just to check, I ran them all through [Combo](https://github.com/RockBrentwood/Combo), applying the extensionality axiom (i.e. the η-rule), and
$$B (S (B Z K)) K,\quad S (K (S (S (K Z) K))) K,$$
both reduce to $C (B Z K)$.

If you want to see the proof in line-by-line form, the best recommendation is to develop the expression $B (S (B Z K)) K$, since you've already seen the proof for $B$ above, which you can treat as a lemma.

If you use $C$, the proof is the 7 lines that make up the construction of $C (B Z K)$. With $B$, it's 11 lines, and if using the pure $S-K-Z$ expression, it's 15 lines. It's always $2n - 1$ lines, where $n$ is the number of combinators involved.

Is there an extension of Curry-Howard that directly incorporates $Z$ as another combinator of some kind? Supposedly, you can integrate this in [Lambda-Mu Calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda-mu_calculus), but I have no experience with that (yet). It is closely and deeply intertwined with [Continuation-Passing Semantics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style) which is the gold standard for programming language semantics, and is also the semantics formalism that's used to integrate [Functional Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming) and [Imperative Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperative_programming). It's probably why they finally got the courage to stick λ-terms from [Lambda Calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus) (the sibling of Combinatory Logic) in languages like [C++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B) in the early 2010's.

**Edit:** Just for the sake of completeness, I lay out the proof with $C$ below:
$$\begin{align}
C:& (c → a → b) → a → c → b,\\
B:& (d → e) → (c → d) → c → e,\\
Z:& (¬b → ¬a) → a → b,\\
BZ:& (c → d) → c → e,\\
K:& c → f → c,\\
BZK:& c → e,\\
C(BZK):& a → c → b,
\end{align}$$
where
$$c = ¬a,\quad d = ¬b → ¬a,\quad e = a → b,\quad f = ¬b,$$
ensures that the applications of Modus Ponens match up.